# How to store an ArrayList ordered with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

The elements in a list are ordered by insertion:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(obj);
```

Now I want to store the list in a postgres table with `hibernate`, and want to preserve the order of insertion. Is that possible that hibernate fetches the collection and it has the same order than before insertion?

Comment: Better to add a order column so you can use it when reading from database. You can use the list index for that.

Comment: Could you give an example how this would look like with annotations?

Answer (score 4):

You will have to persist the order in the database - for example add an `order` property mapped to `ORDER` column

when getting the entities from JPA you will be able to use the [@OrderBy](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html) annotation for sorting

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VEHICLE")
public class Vehicle {

    // other fields here

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vehicle")
    @OrderBy("vehicle.order ASC")
    Set<VehicleImage> vehicleImages;

    public void addImage(VehicleImage image) {
        if (null == vehicleImages) vehicleImages = new HashSet<>();
        image.setSize(vehicleImages.size() + 1);
        image.setVehicle(this);
        vehicleImages.add(this);
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "VEHICLE_IMAGE")
public class VehicleImage{

    // other fields here
    @Column(name = "ORDER")
    private int order;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="VEHICLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    Vehicle vehicle;

}
```

Comment: Can I force hibernate to persist ArrayList elements in the order of insertion? Because then I could just order the elements by `@Id` column, as later inserted elements should occur at the end of the list. Or do I have to use a `Set`, which of course is unordered at first place.

Comment: @membersound you can use List, but you will have to assign the `order` property manually anyway - Hibernate/JPA won't do it for you

Comment: @bedrin Since `Set`s are unordered, does the JPA implementation make sure to use a `SortedSet`? Im truly curious here, didn't really know about the `@OrderBy` annotation.

Comment: You have to use TreeSet, instead of HashSet, implement comparable too, to save order, and have the @OrderBy annotation on the set. You can also skip null check by assigning    SortedSet<VehicleImage> vehicleImages= new TreeSet<>();

Comment: JPA will use a SortedSet implementation if you add `@OrderBy` annotation

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got the following solution:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy...)
@OrderBy("id")
private Set<MyEntity>list = new  LinkedHashSet<>();

@Entity
class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

My requirement is to just preserve the order of insertion, which is given by using a `LinkedHashSet`. As the database `id` is autogenerated and always incremented, I can just order the set by the generated ID and get a list ordered by original insertion order on select.

Comment: what if the id wasn't generated yet ? how would you get your order ?

Comment: `@GeneratedValue` ensures the ID is mandatory and always autogenerated by the db.

Comment: yes I know, the probleme is what if you add 2 objects to your `LinkedHashSet` before they have been persisted how would you ensure the order , since they won't have an ID

Comment: `LinkedHashSet` preserves the order of insertion. On insert I know the order. (reading from csv files).

Comment: and the order would it be the same after they have been persisted ?

Answer (score 0):

Take look at [@OrderColumn](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html) or [this great article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-optimize-unidirectional-collections-with-jpa-and-hibernate/). This will do the job - it will keep order in context of given parent (List collection).